# Проблема с получением данных с базы MongoDB

Tags: c#, node.js, mongodb

Кто то работал с бд MongoDB скинули код nodejs  на шарпе создал модель таблиц, для работы с бд юзаю MongoDB.Driver, но не могу получить даже первого юзера из бд.
Код

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb+srv:/blabla.mongodb.net/curs");
var database = client.GetDatabase("curs");
try
{
    await client.StartSessionAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Ошибка подключения к MongoDB: {ex.Message}");
    return;
}

var collection = database.GetCollection<rfauser>("rfauser");
var firstUser = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).FirstOrDefault();
```

firstUser возвращает null.
Модель

```
 public class rfauser
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int balance { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("ref")]
        public int Ref { get; set; }
        public int idref { get; set; }
        public int epr { get; set; }
        public int eps { get; set; }
        public int invests { get; set; }
        public int epv { get; set; }
        public int pay { get; set; }
        public int part { get; set; }
        public int day { get; set; }
        public int spay { get; set; }
        public string menu { get; set; }
        public string adminmenu { get; set; }
        public string prfUser { get; set; }
        public object prp { get; set; }
        public int akk { get; set; }
        public int pakk { get; set; }
        public int inv { get; set; }
        public string oq { get; set; }
        public int pod { get; set; }
        public string ow { get; set; }
        public string oe { get; set; }
        public string or { get; set; }
        public string ot { get; set; }
        public int send { get; set; }
        public int bonusTimer { get; set; }
        public int viv { get; set; }
        public string regDate { get; set; }
        public bool verify { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: А разве не так нужно: `var firstUser = collection.FirstOrDefault();`? По тому коду как сейчас - как вы найдёте в коллекции объект, который вы только что создали новый? Его же нет в этой коллекции, вот ничего и не находится.

Comment: @CrazyElf у `collection` нету  `.FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Если использовать 
`var firstUser = collection.Find(x => true).FirstOrDefault();`
то также возвращает null

Comment: А, я не прав. Надо так `var firstUser = collection.Find({}).FirstOrDefault();` вроде. Или вообще без аргументов `.Find()` ещё попробовать.

Comment: Сколько элементов в ``collection``? Если она пустая - проблема на стороне выборки из базы, если нет - в выборке ``FirstOrDefault``

Comment: @ValNik где то с тысячу, суть в том что с проекта nodejs надо на c# перенести базу

Comment: @CrazyElf `Или вообще без аргументов .Find() ещё попробовать` там нельзя без аргументов.

Comment: Хорошо, что база не пустая. Сколько элементов в ``collection``  после ``var collection = database.GetCollection<rfauser>("rfauser");``? Типа collection.count=? Может, ищем в пустой комнате)

Comment: ```Наконец, убедитесь, что ваше приложение может получить доступ к серверу MongoDB. Если вы используете хостинг-провайдера, вам может потребоваться обратиться к службе поддержки для настройки вашего приложения на работу с MongoDB.``` Хотя зачем строка подключения если писать в тп для настройки

Comment: @ValNik `Типа collection.count=? Может, ищем в пустой комнате)` если делать так `var collection = database.GetCollection<rfauser>("rfauser").Count(new BsonDocument());` то мы получаем 0. Но комментарий выше гласит про какой то доступ

Comment: Что покажет `ListCollections()`? Будет в списке нужная коллекция?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov _firstBatch = Count = 9, нужная коллекция есть там

Comment: Я хотел попроще. Если `` collection.count=0`` то там ничего и нет. - нужно смотреть на выборку из базы

Comment: Используя примеры отсюда https://metanit.com/sharp/mongodb/1.7.php я по прежнему не могу получить никакие данные из коллекции, имя базы для подключения из списка баз сверил которые могу через Mongo получить, также списки коллекций сверил

Comment: Так а вариант `.Find({})` пробовали, нет?

Comment: @CrazyElf `.Find({""})` вот так в примерах прописано, это тоже не сработало. Скачал MondoDB клиент с офф сайта, экспортировал в json нужные данные из бд для дальнейшего переноса данных. И для работы библиотеки пишут что надо настроить клиент скачанный с офф сайта, и библиотека как обертка для  c# будет работать в приложение. Сильно не разбирался с этим, но не было доступа к данным думаю из за не настроенного клиента.